# Is it possible to have different configuration set for the same key for multiple console apps on windows?

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config, appsettings

I have couple of *console apps* which have the same key in *appsettings.json* **(ConnectionString)**. I need to centralise these connection strings on the machine. The best place I can think of to use *Environment Variables*. These both console apps need to target different databases. I need a way to set key values to different databases. If this was an IIS application then I could use *location* tag in *applicationhost.config* to set different values for them. Can similar approach be used for console apps?

Comment: How do you start the console apps?

Comment: Process.Start from another console app.

Comment: The question is confusing.  Are they separate apps that share an appsettings.json file? If so, change one of the connection string keys to be something else.  If they aren't the same appsettings.json file, why is there a problem?

Comment: we have a CI/CD process which releases these both consoles apps to different locations.  Let's say one is ad C:\Console1, C:\Console2. And you do not want to keep connection strings in the appsettings.json file. What you do is configure those settings on the machine in Environment Variables. Even though these are same console apps they will target different databases.

Comment: It sounds like the connection strings have the same name and will pick up the same environment variable! Have you tried using different connection string names, something more specific to the application/database. This will easily let you then specify different connection strings via the environment.

Comment: @akd then there is nothing out of the box AFAIK. You can use different connection string names.

Comment: Using different connection string names is not an option! This is the same application deployed in 2 different locations. Connection string name is referenced in the project. Using different connection strings name would mean to have 2 separate projects. I wish this can be added similar way as you can do in IIS applications. Like you have location tag and by providing the path of deployed console app and the settings would be read from that section...

Answer (score 0):

> – How do you start the console apps?
> – `Process.Start` from another console app.

And

> Using different connection string names is not an option! This is the same application deployed in 2 different locations.

You need to either implement some magic by hand - for example you can store connection string name in `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
   "ConnectionStringName":"App1ConnectionString"  // App2ConnectionString for the second one
}
```

and the connection string itself in appropriately named environment variable - `ConnectionStrings__App1ConnectionString` and `ConnectionStrings__App2ConnectionString` accordingly. And in the app you will do something like:

```
var connectionStringName = configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStringName");
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
```

But since you are using `Process.Start` you can pass the connection string as a parameter for your app. For example in the app:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    // ...
    .AddEnvironmentVariables() 
    .AddCommandLine(args); // order is important the last added source will have a precedence. 

var connectionString = builder.Build().GetConnectionString("myConnStringName");
Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
```

And on the calling side provide the parameter - something like:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    // ...
    Arguments = "..." + " --ConnectionStrings:myConnStringName=ConnStr1"
};
```